# Select all elements from row to include input field with name array jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having problems selecting input field with name array with the rest of the elements from a row that has: input, select, textarea. I'm doing the following:

```
$(".UpdateMe").click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var row_id = $("#trCharges" + id);

        var row = {};
        $(row_id).find('input,select,textarea').each(function() {
            row[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        });

       console.log(row);

});
```

The above code works on elements's that doesn't have name as an array. For the input with name array It is only getting the last value. I would like to get everything from row including the ones with name array, i.e. field with `name="anarray[]`".

```
 I could separate get each of those input with name array like these:



aname = [];
 $(row_id).find(".NameArray").each(function() {
     aname.push({
         name: $(this).attr('name'),
         value: $(this).val()
     });
 });

 But, I would like to know how to do all together.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `var id = $(this).attr('id')`, please: `var id = this.id`. Also, `row_id` is a jQuery object, you don't (unless there's some context you're not showing/explaining) need to use `find()` to get it, you *already got it*, so `row_id.each(function(){/*...*/})` should work. Albeit there should only be *one* element with that `id`, so you shouldn't need to use `each()`...

Comment: why downvote? I'm seriously trying to get my head around this and cannot get it.

Comment: David Thomas - I get what you said...Updating my function. Though I only get the last value of the name array.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using serializeArray() to get all elements from the row.

```
var params = $(row_id).find('input, select, textarea').serializeArray();

console.log(params);
```

This gave me all values to include those with name array. It is easier than doing it by hand which still don't know how to do it.